# AWS Load Balancer - HTTP Response Headers not passed

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-elb

I have encounter an issue whilst using EB and would appreciate and help that I can get.

I have an HTTP site routing nextjs + flask traffic on port 80 using nginx. The local version of this site runs fine and so does a vanilla Elastic Beanstalk upload. Issues are experienced when setting up and using a load balancer. At the moment I am using a 'Classic Load Balancer' and this is connected to a Cloud Front distribution. What is happening is that Response Headers are not passed back to the client.

What the headers are supposed to look like: [Without loadbalancer on HTTP]

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Server: nginx/1.17.10
Date: Mon, 16 Aug 2021 01:10:02 GMT
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
Set-Cookie: state=; Max-Age=0; Path=/
Set-Cookie: _state=; Max-Age=0; Path=/
Set-Cookie: max_age=; Max-Age=0; Path=/
Set-Cookie: _max_age=; Max-Age=0; Path=/
Set-Cookie: code_verifier=; Max-Age=0; Path=/
Set-Cookie: _code_verifier=; Max-Age=0; Path=/
Set-Cookie: nonce=; Max-Age=0; Path=/
Set-Cookie: _nonce=; Max-Age=0; Path=/
```

What they actually look like: [With loadbalancer + cloudfront on HTTP/HTTPS]

```
HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
Server: nginx/1.17.10
Date: Mon, 16 Aug 2021 01:11:27 GMT
X-Cache: Error from cloudfront
Via: 1.1 71d15e4317f9ba4644f6c17f42ef94c9.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)
X-Amz-Cf-Pop: MXP64-C2
X-Amz-Cf-Id: BYxDl-eFkhRPzAsPUxFv8gxOYT1jeDL6yoPjwqzZ2u4qcSS20B4ReQ==
```

I've tried accessing the Cloud front url through HTTP but the header still do not shown up. Elastic load balancer documentation states that 'if you have a trailing semicolon in the Set-Cookie field of an application cookie, the load balancer ignores the cookie'. Does the example above qualify as such? And if yes it there any way how to go about this?

Comment: I think you're focusing on the wrong part here. The two requests gave different response codes, 400 vs 500 (which likely also explains the different headers). Look at your server logs to see why it returned a 500 when requested from cloudfront.

Comment: It's returning a 500 error due to a null error when attempting to read a value from the response header.

Comment: What is trying to read from the response?

Comment: The request is a proxypass to a NextJS /api/auth/login call which attempts to read various auth parameters (and fails to do so in this particular instance).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix this by replacing the [Classic Load Balancer](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/introduction.html) with an [Application Load Balancer](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/introduction.html) and use that to redirect my HTTP requests to HTTPS rather than Cloudfront.

This can be done by having a single HTTPS listener listening on port 433 which redirects to the default target. As part of the process, one also needs to also choose a security policy (any will do) and assign the relevant SSL certificate.

[image: Listeners]

Click on default-target shown above (or equivalent). If no target is present, click 'Create target group' and in the next page register an origin. (In my case I selected my Elastic Beanstalk application).

[image: Register target]

The application served via Application Load Balancer can be tested by hitting it's DNS.